# Define order of label color in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, uti, sort

I have ordered labeled PDF files with the colors green (very good), orange (ok) and red (bad). When I order my files after labels I get:

- Green
- Orange
- Yellow

But I want to have

- Green
- Yellow
- Orange

Is it possible to configure finder to order labels in my preferred way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

The ordering after colors is alphabetical. The order you want is 'random' and this is not supported by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the label names in Finder preferences so they'll be sorted how you'd like:

[image: Finder Label Preferences]

With label names changed, they now sort like this:

[image: Finder Window with Custom Label Sort Order]